# How can I select multiple lines in Visual mode in VIM?

Tags: vim, vi

When I go to `visual mode` using `v`, I want to select a subset of one line and expand below in the same block, not select the entire next line.

For example, I want to replace all `1`s by `0`s. And I want to select all `1`s in visual mode. But `hjkl` leads to select the entire next line.

[image]

Comment: See `:help ctrl-v`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As stated in the comment, ctrl-v will allow block highlighting.

To make your edit, just position the cursor on the first 1, then hit ctrl-v. Next use the j key to move the cursor down and highlight the other 1's.

Once you have to 1's highlighted that you want to change, r followed by 0 will replace them all with 0's.

Answer (score 3):

`ctrl-v` puts you in visual block mode, which is what you want.